# Apache Solr LocalParams Performance

Tags: performance, solr

I just came across [LocalParams](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LocalParams) in Solr and I was wondering if there is any perfomance impact in using LocalParams over the default way of specifying parameters.

To give you an example of what I mean, consider the following URLs

Default

```
/select?q=dog&defType=dismax&qf=q_title_exact^20.0+q_title+q_suggest^0.5
```

LocalParams

```
/select?q={!type=dismax qf='q_title q_title_exact^20 q_suggest^0.5'}dog
```

While the difference in size is trivial, the fact that I can limit my parameter types to just one, is very beneficial for me.

However, since they are called **Local** Params, I am concerned that using them might have an impact on performance, such as not being cached properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it matters to your cache functionality if you use localparams as compared to default way.The examples that you have given will function identically to each other. However, LocalParams provide an advantage in the following situation (and can affect the records that are stored in cache depending on whether you are doing standard search or using some dismax/edismax searching) :-

Lets say that you want to search for records whose field 'A' match value 'A1' and field 'B' match value 'B1'. Moreover, you want the matching for field 'A' based on dismax parser whereas matching for field 'B' should be done based on the standard parser for solr.

As far as I understand LocalParams, the following code (untested) :-

```
/select?q=A:A1&fq=B:B1&defType=dismax&qf=A^20.0+B^0.5
```

would not serve the purpose since it would perform dismax searching for both field A and field B. However, the following code (untested) :-

```
/select?q={!type=dismax qf='A^20.0 B^0.5}A:A1&fq=B:B1
```

would perform dismax searching across field A whereas standard searching will be done for field B.

So, you can say that LocalParams can help you in performing "different type of search". They have many other advantages depending on the params being used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to repay the favor, if you check 
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax, it states that defType only affects the main query (q). Any other filter queries (fq) will use the default parser.

Comment: My bad. you are correct that defType affects only the main query. However, I only gave that as an example (incorrect though). There are other localParams which you can use such as specifying if the operation should be ANDed or ORed. The reasoning given above applies to all local params. LocalParams provide a way to add meta-data to certain argument types such as query strings (according to wiki).